# How to overwrite list positions based on another list with coordinates - Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a list (chessBoard):

```
chessBoard = [["_|"] * 8 for i in range(8)]
```

and I have a list with coordinates:

```
y = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (5, 2), (5, 4), (2, 1), (2, 5), (4, 1), (4, 5)]
```

For instance if we pick `(5,2)` then I need to replace whatever is on 5th column 2nd row in list `x` with `'*'`. I am kind of lost how to do it, maybe I should use an array instead of `x` list. Like I said - I don't know. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
chessBoard = [["|_"] * 8 for i in range(8)]
moves = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (5, 2), (5, 4), (2, 1), (2, 5), (4, 1), (4, 5)]

index_to_letter = {
    0: "a",
    1: "b",
    2: "c",
    3: "d",
    4: "e",
    5: "f",
    6: "g",
    7: "h"
}

def test():
    x = 0
    y = 8
    for i in range(len(chessBoard)):
        print(*chessBoard[i],end="")
        if i%8==x:
            print("",y)
        x += 1
        y -= 1
    for i in range(8):
        print("",index_to_letter[i],end=" ")

test()
```

Comment: Hey! What does your code look like so far? Unless you do not provide a  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve your question is going to be deleted.

Comment: With _what_ do you want to replace the value at `(3, 6)`? Shouldn't there be a third value?

Comment: Just some symbol, for instance `*`. Doesn't matter.

Comment: Your code is invalid. Can you fix it?

Comment: Are those `"_|"` supposed to form a grid when printed? Don't put the layout stuff into the grid; this will make updating values and generally working with the "chess board" much _much_ harder.

Comment: so why don't you just use **indexing**? like `chessboard[5][2] = '*'`

Comment: Code fixed. Sorry for that.

Comment: if you just store '_' or '*' values in your chessboard as suggested above you can get the same output by replacing `print(*chessBoard[i],end="")` with `print("|".join(chessboard[i]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified data format. With it, it becomes easier to show moves and display the whole grid:

```
chessBoard = [["_"] * 8 for i in range(8)]
moves = [(1, 2),(1, 4),(5, 2),(5, 4),(2, 1),(2, 5),(4, 1),(4, 5)]

# Add a symbol on the grid for every move
for i, j in moves:
    chessBoard[i][j] = "X"

index_to_letter = 'abcdefgh'

# Display board with row numbers
for i, row in enumerate(chessBoard):
    print(' | '.join(row) + ' ' + index_to_letter[i])
```

It outputs:

```
_ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ a
_ | _ | X | _ | X | _ | _ | _ b
_ | X | _ | _ | _ | X | _ | _ c
_ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ d
_ | X | _ | _ | _ | X | _ | _ e
_ | _ | X | _ | X | _ | _ | _ f
_ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ g
_ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ h
```